# Variational differentional equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $f \in C^1(D)$, $D$ compact, there exists unique solutions (locally) for

$\dot{y} = f(t,y)$, $y(t_0) = y_0$.

We denote the solution with $y(t;t_0,y_0)$.

Let $G(t;t_0,y_0) := \frac{\partial}{\partial y_0} y (t;t_0,y_0)$ and $g(t;t_0,y_0) := \frac{\partial}{\partial t_0} y (t;t_0,y_0)$.

The initial value problem

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} G(t;t_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(t,y(t;t_0,y_0)) \cdot G(t;t_0,y_0) $
$G(t_0;t_0,y_0) = I$

is called Variational differential equation 1 (VDE1).

And the initial value problem

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(t;t_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(t,y(t;t_0,y_0)) \cdot g(t;t_0,y_0) $
$g(t_0;t_0,y_0) = -f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$

is called VDE2.

In the lecture we proved a lemma:

$g(t;t_0,y_0) = -G(t;t_0,y_0)f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$

The proof goes like this:

We took VDE1 and multiplied $f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$ on both equations.
Let us call these equations (1).

We defined $\gamma(t;t_0,y_0):= -G(t;t_0,y_0)f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$ and rewrote (1) as

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \gamma(t;t_0,y_0) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(t,y(t;t_0,y_0)) \cdot \gamma(t;t_0,y_0) $
$\gamma(t_0;t_0,y_0) = -f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$

This is VDE2 and due to uniqueness (Picard Lindelöf) we have

$\gamma(t;t_0,y_0) = g(t;t_0,y_0)$ (2)

And I don't understand the last step.
Where does this uniqueness come from, so that (2) holds?
I don't see how Picard Lindelöf can help us here.

Comment: Several times, you write the variable $s$ in your differential equations (specifically, in VD1 and VD2, then later).  Are you sure these are supposed to be $s$ and not $t$?

Comment: You are right. I fixed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right: Picard-Lindelöf isn't acutally needed, and isn't actually strong enough to do what this lemma says.  The lemma is still true, though.  For the moment, assume $f\in C^2(D)$.  I WILL use Picard-Lindelöf.  I'll talk about $f\in C^1(D)$ at the end.

At some point, you said that VD1 was multiplied on both sides by $f_0=f(t_0,y(t_0;t_0,y_0))$.  This gives the IVP \begin{align}G' f_0&=f_y(t,y)Gf_0 \\ G(t_0)f_0&=f_0.\end{align}  Here, I'm using prime to denote differentiation with respect to $t$, subscripts for differentials (eg. $f_y=D_yf$), and I'm suppressing variables a bit for cleanliness. Since $f_0$ is a constant, I can factor this more suggestively:\begin{align}(Gf_0)'&=f_y(t,y)Gf_0 \\ Gf_0(t_0)&=f_0.\end{align}  So now, define $\gamma=-Gf_0$ as you did in class.  If we calculate $\gamma'=-(Gf_0)'$ and compare to the above differential equation, we see that $\gamma$ satisfies what I will call **(EQ1)**: \begin{align}\gamma'&=f_y(t,y)\gamma \\ \gamma(t_0)&=-f_0.\end{align} Compare the above differential equation with **(VD2)**: \begin{align}g'&=f_y(t,y)g\\ g(t_0)&=-f_0.\end{align} The differential equations are identical (since their time-dependent vector fields are both $(t,z)\mapsto f_y(t,y)z$ ), and their initial conditions are the same (they're both $-f_0$).  Therefore, the associated solutions are equal.  Since $f$ is $C^2$, $t\mapsto f_y(t,y(t))$ is $C^1$, and so is Lipschitz continuous on $D$.  Picard-Lindelöf guarantees that there is exactly one solution, so we are permitted to write unambiguously $\gamma(t;t_0,y_0)=g(t;t_0,y_0)$.

The reason we used Picard-Lindelöf (P.L) is because we wanted to write $\gamma=g$, and this only makes sense if there is only *one* $\gamma$ and *one* $g$: we need there to be a unique solution.  If $f$ was irregular in some way, so that there was more than one distinct solution to the initial value problem, then of course we would need to specify which $\gamma$ solution was equal to which $g$ solution.  But this is very complicated business, since usually, when there is a lack of unicity of solutions, it is because there are infinitely many.  If we didn't have uniqueness, but were only guaranteed existence, then the result would be weakened to something like:

**For *each* solution $\gamma$ of the IVP (EQ1), there *exists* a solution $g$ of the IVP (VD2) such that $\gamma=g$.**

And then, re-write that in terms of the $G$ function.  The above result isn't nearly as nice though.  Uniqueness gives us the clean, unambiguous equality $g=-Gf_0$, and we used the P.L theorem to do that.

If $f$ is only $C^1$, then $t\mapsto f_y(t,y(t))$ is continuous (but possibly not Lipschitz).  The right hand side is a square matrix of appropriate size, so the differential equation $g'=f_y(t,y)g$ is linear.  Since continuity of $A(t)$ is enough to guarantee local existence/uniqueness of solutions of $x'=A(t)x$, we get the desired existence/uniqueness result for (EQ1) and (VD2).

Comment: Thanks. This turned to be more complicated than I thought.